# Store table efficiently in array SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, stored-procedures

I have a table like

```
a1 a2 a3 a4
-----------
1  11 21 31
2  12 22 32
3  13 23 33
4  14 24 34
5  15 25 35
6  16 26 36
7  17 27 37
8  18 28 38 
9  19 29 39
10 20 30 40
```

What is it the best way to store it in a c sharp array, as i am reading from sql server 2008 in a stored procedure, in COLUM MAJOR ORDER?

```
array = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,......40
```

is it better to store it like ROW MAJOR ORDER?, Which one is more efficent?

```
array = 1, 11, 21, 31,2,12,22,32,3,13,23,24,....10,20,30,40
```

I am using

```
SqlDataReader rdr = null;
// create a connection object
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
// create a command object
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("select * from a1,a2,a3,a4", conn);
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with the collection? Do you need to store it as an array?

Comment: How are you reading the values from the database?

Comment: Wait, are you planning on storing the entire array as a comma-separated list in the Database, is that what you're asking?  Otherwise, it's probably going to come down to access patterns...

Comment: I want to store the whole table as a unidimensional array, I am using the reader function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row major order would be easier to code since records are processed row-by-row.  To store it in column major order you'd have to load all of the records into a data structure in memory (DataTable?) and loop over it for each column.

However, without knowing the purpose of storing in on one vector, if the values are in the order you show of it it's just dummy data, etc. it's hard to give a definitibe answer on what's more "efficient".

Comment: The purpose of storing data like an array is manipulating data for statistics and some numerical methods, so I would prefer to use rROW MAJOR ORDER